flutter plugin related issue
PS E:\projectsample\my_flutter_project\my_flutter_project> flutter run     
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1971 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Value 'C:Program FilesJavajdk-17' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             950ms
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried any methods and like making changes to the build.gradle...almost all th gradles have been modified according to chatgpt and also an error shown on the android is   The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Could not create task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugUnitTestSources'.
this and base files have different roots: E:\projectsample\my_flutter_project\my_flutter_project\build\path_provider_android and C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\path_provider_android-2.2.15\android.

Sounds like you have set C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 as the value in a .properties file, and did not take into account that the backslash is an escape in .properties files, which is removed if it is not used in a defined escape. Use either C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17 in .properties, or properly escape the backslash in properties: C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17. That said, without a [mre], that is just a guess.
